# How do you feed in an entire directory of input files using cat in Unix?

Tags: unix

I'd like to run a program on a directory of files. I know how to do this with one file, using

`cat myFile.xml | myProgram.py`.

How can I run myProgram.py over a folder, say myFolder?

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like

```
ls | xargs cat
```

for its functional language feel.  YMMV.

Comment: How the heck did I never hear about this before? +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your program can accept a filename as its first command line argument, one way is to use `find` to find all the files in the folder, and then use `xargs` to run your program for each of them:

```
find myFolder | xargs -n 1 myProgram.py
```

The `-n 1` means "run the program once per file".  If your program is happy to receive multiple filenames on its command line, you can omit the `-n 1` and `xargs` will run your program fewer times with multiple files on its command line.

(`find` will do a recursive search, so you'll get all the files in *and under* myFolder.  You can use `find myFolder -maxdepth 1` to prevent that.)

(Thanks to @Personman for pointing out that this will run the program for the folder itself as well as the files.  You can use `find myFolder -type f` to tell `find` to only return regular files.)

Comment: Gotta be careful with find. First of all, you need the trailing slash in 'find myFolder/'. Second, be aware that find returns the folder itself, as well as all its contents, and unless you use -maxdepth, it does so recursively too. Find is pretty complicated; you should read its manpage first.

Comment: Seems like overkill based on the OP.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
for x in myFolder/*
do
cat $x | myProgram.py
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to execute your data program on a bunch of files, the easiest/least complicated way is to use -exec in find.

Say you wanted to execute data on all txt files in the current directory (and subdirectories). This is all you'd need:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec data {} \;
```

If you wanted to restrict it to the current directory, you could do this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.txt" -exec data {} \;
```

There are lots of options with find.

Answer (score 0):

`cat myFolder/* | myProgram.py`

Comment: does this run myProgram once for each file in myFolder?

Comment: @Sanjay: no, this will concatenate all the files into one stream which myProgram.py will see on stdin. If the OP wants myProgram.py to be invoked once for each file then he needs to state that in his question, and one of the find/xargs answers would then be more apporpriate in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Or `cat *.xml | myProgram.py` that will produce the output of every .xml file to stdin then piped to your program. This combines all files into one stream.

`myProgram.py *.xml` will expand every filename as input to your program like this: `myProgram.py file1.xml file2.xml file3.xml ... filen.xml` Each file remains separate and the script can tell one from another.

Python / Perl / sh scripts, base case, usually handle that the same as `myProgram.py file1.xml; myProgram.py file2.xml; myProgram.py filen.xml` with the `;` meaning new command.

Play with it and welcome to Unix!